compare cell 2 with cell 1 and show result
I need help on below scenario,
If Snap_Id is not null then the previous row should be Yes else No



Id
CaseId
User
CaseStatus
DateCreated
Snap_Id
row_num




11
100
Raj
3
2023-04-27
null
1


22
100
Mike
3
2023-06-22
null
2


33
100
RJ
5
2023-06-30
33
3


44
100
Mike
3
2023-07-04
null
4


55
100
RJ
5
2023-07-04
55
5



Can you please help me to write SQL statement to achieve the output.
The final output I am expecting is as below,



Id
CaseId
User
CaseStatus
DateCreated
Snap_Id
row_num
Result




11
100
Raj
3
2023-04-27
null
1
No


22
100
Mike
3
2023-06-22
null
2
Yes


33
100
RJ
5
2023-06-30
33
3
No


44
100
Mike
3
2023-07-04
null
4
Yes


55
100
RJ
5
2023-07-04
55
5
No



Hope you can help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

@JonasMetzler, It looks perfect. Thank you so much.

Look into lag

@Andrew, Thank you for suggestion, Is it possible to help me with sql query?

I created a fiddle that might help us collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/WlKAOVvy

Your sample results don't follow your logic. Row2 is the same as Row1 (both NULL) but the result on Row2 is Yes which you said means that they differ. One Row1, where there is no previous record, what would the result be?

@Abhi I don't get this and agree with Alan there is some mismatch between the expected result and the explained logic. Please improve your question.

@AlanSchofield, agree, I edited the question. Hope I explained what I need

@JonasMetzler, agree. Edited the question

"I tried self join".  So where is this try???

Cells aren't a thing in database, rits rows and columns

@Eric, The self join I tried did not work at all, so discarded that query

@DaleK, that is right, I gave sample screen from excel so refer the same but indeed its column I am referring to

It still doesn't make sense.  Can you put the explanation against every row in  your expected results because as it stands, logic you explain at the start of the question does not seem to match your results.

@AlanSchofield, hope this is clear now.


If Snap_Id row is not null then the previous row should be Yes else No

It is clearer if you rephrased it as if Snap_Id of next row is not null then the result should be Yes else No
Result = case when lead(Snap_Id) over (order by row_num) is not null
              then 'Yes'
              else 'No'
              end


This produces too many Yes answers?  (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/HN-DwLxf )

in the dbfiddle, the snap_id is a string value null

Ok, overlooked that.... , changed it to null (not the string), now it works: https://dbfiddle.uk/peet_Yn2
